# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document in vc++(visual studio 2013)

Tags: c++, debugging

There is similar question posted in this forum and I tried it too but unfortunately did not get work. Therefore I am putting this question again.

I am trying to debug V3 printer driver project in visual studio 2013. when I attached a debugger to `printerpipeline.exe` process and stick a breakpoint in `renderfilter.cpp`, suddenly I got the

> 'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.'

I tried to change `Debug->Exceptions` options, and `Tools->Options->Debugging`, but both cases didn't work for me.

If anybody know how to resolve this problem, please do let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You need debugging symbols (aka `.pdb`-files) for the binaries you are trying to debug.

So in your case this means you'll need a `.pdb` for at least `printerpipeline.exe`, but potentially for any loaded `.dll`s as well.

If you have built that `.exe` yourself, it might mean that the `.pdb` is out of sync with the binary, and a rebuild may fix that.

If that binary is a third party application, you will need to get the debugging symbols from the vendor.

Comment: Thanks tehlexx for this replay, there is only one netfabb dll from third party but remaining dlls are from my project. that dlls shows can not find open the pdb file in DEBUG->WINDOWS->MODULES option

Comment: Did you build your binaries in Release mode? By default, I believe no `.pdb`s are generated for Release, you will need to enable that in your project settings, or use a Debug build.

Comment: I am building it in debug mode, but still having same problem.. :(

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your solution and re-building it? Can you verify the `.pdb`-files are in your output directory?

Comment: In the Modules window you can right click and add your Debug output folder to folders where your system looks for symbol files. Also, the thing that worked for me was deleting all the output files manually, Clean won't do it every time and that's why even though the .pdb file is generated, it doesn't correspond to your output files, thus not loading symbols from it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For me, changing

**set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd" )**  to  **set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")**

in my CMakeLists.txt solved it.